# Sending SSRS report to each and every agent for their next day schedule every day at 4 pm

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, bids

I need a help in deciding how to get this task finish.

I created SSRS report. which is taking 4 parameters. They are as follows.

- Date(By default is Today's Date)
- Site (Different Office Location)
- Service Provider's Name ( Agent's    name who will do the service)
- Type    of service (Air conditioning    repair, Furnace Repair,
  Window Repair    etc)

I am able to run the report via selecting each parameter since they all are single value parameters.

Now I want to email this report as an email attachment for each Provider(Agent) for their daily schedule(Next Day).

So I am hoping that I have to run the report and select each and every Site then each and every associated provider's name to the selected site and then each and every associated service to the selected providers. Here I don't have to select the day since Date will be by default Tomorrow's date which report will take as parameter.

How can I do this via some kind of SQL or SSRS tool or is there any functionality that BIDS has?

Please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a data-driven subscription. To configure this, start by going to your Report Manager or SharePoint, wherever you're hosting the report. Next, you'll need to write a small query that returns the parameters you want to run the report with. In other words, it should return one row for each version of the report you want to send out. Next, it will ask you to fill out your email settings. You can set fields like the "To" address and your parameters to be populated by a column from your query. The last step is to set up the scheduling.

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply! Can I do this with R-Tag do you think?

Comment: @user2040021 Sorry, I don't know anything about R-Tag.

Comment: OK np. I already started with Report Manager. but just wondering how to get email list for all users.